# Given $f'(a) > 0$, prove that $f$ is increasing on $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$.

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Suppose that $f'(a) > 0$ in an interior point $a$ of the domain. Prove that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $f$ is increasing on the open interval $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$.

**My attempt:** Suppose $f'(a) = L > 0$. This means that $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} > 0. $$ By definition, then, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $$ 0 < | h | < \delta \Rightarrow \bigg| \frac{ f(a + h) - f(a) }{h} - L \bigg| < \epsilon. $$ If we choose $\epsilon = L > 0$, then this means that $$ \frac{f(a +h) - f(a) }{h} > 0 \qquad (*) $$ whenever $ 0 < |h| < \delta$. I now need to prove $f$ is increasing on $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$. Let $x,y \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$, and suppose that $x \leq y$. Then we need to prove that $f(x)  \leq f(y)$. I want to somehow use (*) for this, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: $f'(a)$ is also $\gt \epsilon$ in a region $\pm \delta$ around $a$

Comment: I don't think this is true, since we could have $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)+x/2$ and $a=0$. Then we have $f'(0)=0.5$, but $f$ is decreasing for values of $x$ arbitrarily close to $0$. You need to assume that $f$ is _continuously_ differentiable, i.e. $f'(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: @Arthur, but your function is not defined at the point $a = 0$?

Comment: @Kamil That is a very valid point that I forgot to account for. Use $$g(x)=\cases{0&if $x=0$\\f(x)&otherwise}$$instead, and it will work. It's such a common example that you often see it referred to as in my previous comment. That way is much simpler, but technically not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f$ is $C^1$, (continuously differentiable), if $f'(a)>0$, it implies that there exists $c:$ $f'(x)>0$ for $x\in [a-c,a+c]$. Then for $u<v,\in [a-c,a+c]$, apply the mean value theorem $f(v)-f(u)=f'(w)(v-u)>0, w\in [u,v]$.

In general if $f$ is not $C^1$, the function may not be increasing has point out some comments

Comment: $C^1$ was not supposed.

Comment: I know have you read my answer completely?

Answer (score 2):

Usually one defines $f$ to be increasing on an non-empty interval $J$ if for all $x,y\in J$ it holds that $x< y\Rightarrow f(x)\le f(y)$.  But you can't deduce that solely from $f'(a)>0$.  Take as example 
$$f(x):=\begin{cases}
\tan(x),&\text{if $x$ is rational;}\\
x,&\text{else.}
\end{cases}$$
where $a=0$.

What can be shown instead is
$$x<0<y\Rightarrow f(x)<f(y),$$
which is a sort of punctual comparison, not a local one.